# Can't resolve domain names in php under apache

Tags: php, linux, apache, dns

I'm at my wits end with this one.  I have apache running on a server of mine (an Amazon ec2 instance), and I can't seem to resolve domain names in php.  For example fopen('http://www.google.com', 'r') will throw "php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known", but if I change the url to one of google's ip addresses it will work fine.  Pinging www.google.com on the remote server works fine as well so I know its not a problem with the "outer system."

The peculiar thing is that I've had this server up and running for a while without any issues and I can't think of anything I did that could have caused this.

In my php.ini I have allow_url_fopen = On and to make sure it was being applied I ran phpinfo() from the same script that is having this problem and allow_url_fopen is in fact turned on.

Any ideas of what else I should try?  Could some sort of file permissions problem be causing this?  Because I did change some file permissions inside my webapp, and I suppose its possible I mistyped something and accidentally changed permissions/owenership of some files outside of the app.  Its highly unlikely but I can't think of anything else I did on the system that could have stopped this from working.

Comment: If I run the php script from the command line on the server the domain names are resolved fine, so I guess it has something to do with apache?

Comment: I found a bunch of posts by people online having the same problem.  For most of them restarting the server resolves it but not for me.  For others its a permissions problem, but I made sure /etc/resolv.conf has read permissions for everyone and I'm running Apache as root anyways...

Comment: Is there anything in the Apache or kernel logs? Alternatively as a workaround, you could do your own DNS lookup using [net_dns2](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_DNS2/redirected) or [PHPDNS](http://www.purplepixie.org/phpdns/).

Comment: How about SELinux policies? `setsebool -P nis_enabled 1`, 
`setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1`.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem.

After **httpd restart** host resolve problem continues. 
But with **httpd stop & start** problem solved for me.

Comment: Thanks, this solved an issue for me as well. `service https graceful` didn't help, but a stop and start did the trick. Does anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 3):

If you have permission, try changing the name servers in your /etc/resolv.conf file to other nameservers. Might be your dns cache is old,

or try changing the SE Linux Policy by running these commands in terminal:

```
setsebool -P nis_enabled 1
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it's because of Apache? First step I would do is run the following script in the terminal. You should see all the HTML text printed out:

```
<?php
$handle = @fopen("http://www.google.com", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
        echo $buffer;
    }
    if (!feof($handle)) {
        echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

If that's not working, the next step is to check if your DNS resolver is working. What's the output of

```
host www.google.com
```

After doing these two tests, we can decide which direction to move in.

Comment: Thanks, I already ran an equivalent test.  Running a php script with fopen in it from the command line will work fine.  Running the same script through apache will fail with "php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known"

Comment: Try changing to cUrl. Some implementations of getaddrinfo are broken.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in my development that only occurs executing php under apache, but directly with php, it works!

```
php filetest.php
```

Then I checked my apache status and I saw this in log:

```
Mar 12 13:01:08 arch-linux apachectl[6847]: AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using fe80::6aa3:c4ff:fe...is message
```

After some search I found it:

```
http://tutorialforlinux.blogspot.com.br/2013/10/solve-problem-ah00558-when-restarting.html
```

And this was the exaclty problem, then I changed this in my httpd.conf:

```
#ServerName www.example.com:80
```

To this:

```
ServerName localhost
```

It works, now I can resolve dns in php under apache.

Sorry about my bad english, I would like to detail more.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `file_get_contents`:

```
file_get_contents('http://www.google.com');
```

`fopen` and `file_get_contents` are nearly equivalent but don't always work under the same configurations on the server.

Comment: Thanks, but its not my app I am trying to get working.  phpmyadmin, adminer, sqlbuddy, or any mysql management program can't access a remote database I am trying to connect to.

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to add comments). Looks to me that this could be related to running Apache in a chrooted environment.